# What is the optimal way to store a large graph in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am storing it as an array of vertex objects that have an array field that lists its neighbors. However, this seems to be an extremely inefficient method of doing so. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that is inefficient? Define large in this context. Are you worried about memory usage or efficiency when traversing the graph? What kind of algorithms do you want to run on that graph?

Comment: Obviously there are tradeoffs and it depends on your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [directed_graph gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/directed_graph), from the [directed_graph docs](https://github.com/MrPowers/directed_graph):

> The directed_graph gem is useful for modeling directed, acyclic, unweighted graphs. It provides methods to topologically sort graphs, find the shortest path between two vertices, and render the graphs and json for client-side graphing.

The Graph class should be instantiated with an array of edges:

```
# create the vertices
@root = Vertex.new(name: "root")
@a = Vertex.new(name: "a")
@b = Vertex.new(name: "b")
@c = Vertex.new(name: "c")
@d = Vertex.new(name: "d")
@e = Vertex.new(name: "e")

# The first argument is the origin_vertex
# and the second is the destination_vertex
@ra = Edge.new(origin_vertex: @root, destination_vertex: @a)
@ab = Edge.new(origin_vertex: @a, destination_vertex: @b)
@bc = Edge.new(origin_vertex: @b, destination_vertex: @c)
@bd = Edge.new(origin_vertex: @b, destination_vertex: @d)
@ae = Edge.new(origin_vertex: @a, destination_vertex: @e)
@de = Edge.new(origin_vertex: @d, destination_vertex: @e)
@edges = [@ra, @ab, @bc, @bd, @ae, @de]
@graph = Graph.new(@edges)
```

The @graph object can be used to get a topological sorted array of the vertices:

```
@graph.sorted_vertices # [@root, @a, @b, @d, @e, @c]
```

Comment: why the downvote @sawa? Just because you disagree does not make my answer wrong. I provided a well documented answer with a link to an up to date and well documented library that seems to do exactly what the OP asked.

Comment: @sawa Berating someone for using a library is pretty cold. If you have a specific issue with this particular library that's worth bringing up, but to blanket complain about "another layer of software" is downright confusing. Rubygems has a lot of high quality modules worth using when they do the job.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I totally agree, and anytime I find a library that does the job well I prefer to use that rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @sawa I think you may have jumped to conclusions about the OP's original meaning when he uses the word 'efficient'`. You believe that he is referring to memory and space considerations. I respect your opinion; but I disagree. I believe he is searching for an all around better way to work with graphs in Ruby.

Comment: @sawa "Efficient" is largely a factor of the hardware involved, the dataset size, and the performance requirements. If this code meets all those requirements then it's efficient enough. Working code first, optimized code second. Always avoid premature optimization.

Comment: I unfortunately did not see the answer until now, and to answer a question I saw above, the graph has several thousand vertices (but not many edges) and required a method of traversing vertices efficiently. It turns out hashes are an excellent way of achieving this, but the library provided in the answer seems promising as well

Comment: @SamSomeone I'm glad you found an appropriate data structure. Cheers!